# Using XAMPP, Error 403 Access Forbidden

Tags: xampp

**Update (FOUND A WORKING SOLUTION):**
http://maff.ailoo.net/2008/07/set-up-multiple-virtual-hosts-on-xampp-for-windows/

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
 DocumentRoot D:/srv/xampp/projects/testproject/public
 ServerName testproject

 <Directory "D:/srv/xampp/projects/testproject/public">
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
  AllowOverride All
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
 </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

---

I had tried re-installing, and no luck. I am using XAMPP 1.7.3, Windows 7 64bit.

Followed instructions from: [403 Forbidden Error when trying to view localhost on Apache](https://superuser.com/questions/68857/403-forbidden-error-when-trying-to-view-localhost-on-apache/69092#69092)

```
[Sat Oct 16 16:09:54 2010] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Sat Oct 16 16:09:54 2010] [notice] Digest: done
[Sat Oct 16 16:09:54 2010] [notice] Apache/2.2.14 (Win32) DAV/2 mod_ssl/2.2.14 OpenSSL/0.9.8l mod_autoindex_color PHP/5.3.1 mod_apreq2-20090110/2.7.1 mod_perl/2.0.4 Perl/v5.10.1 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sat Oct 16 16:09:54 2010] [notice] Server built: Nov 11 2009 14:29:03
[Sat Oct 16 16:09:54 2010] [notice] Parent: Created child process 4960
[Sat Oct 16 16:09:58 2010] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Sat Oct 16 16:09:58 2010] [notice] Digest: done
[Sat Oct 16 16:09:59 2010] [notice] Child 4960: Child process is running
[Sat Oct 16 16:09:59 2010] [notice] Child 4960: Acquired the start mutex.
[Sat Oct 16 16:09:59 2010] [notice] Child 4960: Starting 150 worker threads.
[Sat Oct 16 16:09:59 2010] [notice] Child 4960: Starting thread to listen on port 443.
[Sat Oct 16 16:09:59 2010] [notice] Child 4960: Starting thread to listen on port 80.
[Sat Oct 16 16:09:59 2010] [notice] Child 4960: Starting thread to listen on port 443.
[Sat Oct 16 16:09:59 2010] [notice] Child 4960: Starting thread to listen on port 80.
[Sat Oct 16 16:10:30 2010] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] client denied by server configuration: C:/projects/test/
[Sat Oct 16 16:10:36 2010] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] client denied by server configuration: C:/projects/test/favicon.ico
```

vhosts file:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ##ServerAdmin postmaster@dummy-host2.localhost
    DocumentRoot "C:/projects/test"
    ServerName test
    ##ServerAlias www.dummy-host2.localhost
    ##ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host2.localhost-error.log"
    ##CustomLog "logs/dummy-host2.localhost-access.log" combined
</VirtualHost>
```

hosts:

```
# Virtual host
127.0.0.1    test
```

Comment: Might want to post your working solution as an answer @Doug

Comment: I will do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**(FOUND A WORKING SOLUTION):**
http://maff.ailoo.net/2008/07/set-up-multiple-virtual-hosts-on-xampp-for-windows/

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
 DocumentRoot D:/srv/xampp/projects/testproject/public
 ServerName testproject

 <Directory "D:/srv/xampp/projects/testproject/public">
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
  AllowOverride All
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
 </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me with Ubuntu 11.10 and version 1.7.7
in httpd.conf i've added the # in the directory to have it work with vhosts.
My vhosts were located outside of the root folder...

And change user and group from nobody to your username:

```
User nobody
Group nobody
</IfModule>
</IfModule>

#
# Each directory to which Apache has access can be configured with respect
# to which services and features are allowed and/or disabled in that
# directory (and its subdirectories).
#
# First, we configure the "default" to be a very restrictive set of
# features.
#
<Directory />
# Options FollowSymLinks
# AllowOverride None
# Order deny,allow
# Deny from all
</Directory>
```

Comment: Thanks, commenting out the directory stuff solved my problem with 403 errors on development files that weren't in the root. eg /home/sites/mysite vs server root in /opt/lampp/htdocs

Answer (score 1):

In the apache folder, go to `extra` and then open file `httpd-xamp.conf`.

Edit the following lines:

```
<LocationMatch "^/(?i:(?:xampp|security|licenses|phpmyadmin|webalizer|server-status|server-info))">
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.0/8 
    ErrorDocument 403 /error/HTTP_XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
</LocationMatch>
```

Change the above configuration like below:

```
<LocationMatch "^/(?i:(?:xampp|security|licenses|phpmyadmin|webalizer|server-status|server-info))">
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from all
    ErrorDocument 403 /error/HTTP_XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
</LocationMatch>
```

Now restart XAMPP, it will work.

Comment: Didn't work for me :(

Answer (score 1):

Here is an update for newer versions of XAMMP. The syntax has changed a little. Note the line: Require all granted in the Directory block.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
  DocumentRoot D:/srv/xampp/projects/testproject/public
  ServerName testproject

 <Directory "D:/srv/xampp/projects/testproject/public">
   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
   AllowOverride All
   Require all granted
 </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I already had proper settings.

**Solution:** recreate file `httpd-xamp.conf`

*It's in the apache folder: `extra` subdir.*

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).